# not full length, rounded bottom border

Tags: css

How can I make a line under a , not stretch the whole way, lets say 70% centered and with rounded borders, see image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbliZ.png

this is what I got so far, but its obviously not rounded, and its goes 100% of the width of the span.

```
<span class="button">
  hello space!
</span>
```

```
.button{
  border-bottom:6px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `::after` element.

```css
.button {
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<span class="button">
  hello space!
</span>
```